# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Problem | Reached target Cloud-init target.scripts.=/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net] [dsmode=net]. UP

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, vmware

Problem: Ubuntu 18.04.3 Reached target Cloud-init target.scripts.=/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net] [dsmode=net]. UP

Hello Smart People,

we have a Seafile Server running on Ubuntu.
This Server is hosted on our Local VMWARE vSphere. I have 0 Knowledge with Ubuntu or Linux and we usually just start the Server and we can access and share Files via a website.
For Maintanence I logged into Seafile but this GUI doesnt open up anymore.
Theres just the Terminal (I think its called tty1?) and i cant really type into it.

I cant press Enter or CTRL+C to Continue. CTRL+ALT+F2-6 just switches to the other Terminals and i can SSH into it too. But the GUI that iam familiar with doesnt work anymore..

The Server looks like its working but we have to add more space to the machine.

Please help me/us

Image Link from my Terminal:
[image: Seafile]

Comment: Also when I start the Server it says error: no video mode
Is it maybe because of that? I couldnt find anything online :(

Comment: Yes it is. It starts the diplay-manager without a display. Sounds weird. Did you change graphics card (or update its firmware or something)? Did you change grub settings?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the windowing display is not part of the kernel <sup>*1</sup> but rather is managed through an ordinary process. For some reason this process is no longer starting up.

You've already noted the multiple `VT` terminals; if there's a window manager running, it's usually on `tty7` (`ctrl+alt+F7` <sup>*2</sup>) since that's the first unused one after the six that are started by default.

Using ssh, have a look in `/var/log/Xorg*.log` to see any errors (lines marked with `(EE)`) that would indicate why the window manager isn't starting up. Post the error messages here if they're not obvious to you.

You could also try using remote windows (ie, display the windows on your desktop machine, rather than on the console of the server). For a Linux desktop it's simply a matter of running `ssh -X server` to create an `X11` tunnel back to your desktop.

For a Windows desktop you'll need to start some kind of Xorg compatibility service, and then run that ssh command. If you can start a command line in WSL that might suffice. (As I do not possess any devices with Windows installed I'll have to leave it to others to fill in more details for this option.)

If the server has a web interface, make sure the web browser is running on the desktop, rather than on the server using the X tunnel.

Streaming video may not work over ssh, but if you're just using an administrative interface that's unlikely to be an issue.

---

*1: Wayland does some low-level windowing functions in the kernel, but still manages this from userspace.

*2: The `ctrl-alt-Fn` keychords only need `ctrl` when you're escaping from the windowing display (which you currently don't have); once you're in the VT subsystem you can switch with just `alt-Fn` or `alt ←` and `alt →`.